# With a file with 750 permission, which group has "5" permission?

Tags: permissions

The bits 750 invoke the `-rwxr-x---` permissions, on a given file, to the user who owns the file and "the" group. My query regards the group. Which group on the system would receive these permissions?

Am I right in assuming that they would be awarded to the group that the owner belongs to? If so, is this **always** the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Am I right in assuming that they would be awarded to the group that the owner belongs to?**
Wrong. A file can belong to any user and any group. There is no relationship between user and group in such way.

Every file has user owner and group owner. These are separate entities. If you do `ls -l` it will show you owner user and owner group of every file, e.g.:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 user_owner group_owner   22K May  2 13:06 file.png
-rw-r--r--  1 user_owner group_owner   22K May  2 13:12 file.jpg
```

To change user owner, you use `chown` command. To change group owner, you use `chgrp` command.

You can also use `chown` and specify both, user and a group, by separating them with colon like this:

```
$ chown user:group file
```